# What's injected interception?

Tags: spyware, sniffing, tls-intercept

I was reading [this pdf](https://www.slideshare.net/FabioGhioni/fabio-ghioni-asymmetric-warfare-and-interception-revealed) and at slide number 23 and 24 I read "injected interception". What's that means ?
in my mind it should be a type of interception that are made by injection. I mean I inject something (for example an image) in a data stream that help me in decryption and interception.
My question is: what's mean "injected interception" ?
I searched on google but I didn't understand what's mean and I didn't find any information.
Hope now is more clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given context it basically means somehow adding a backdoor to the client or server and thus getting access to the plain data before it gets encrypted or after it got decrypted. This is the common way to get around solid encryption which makes it impossible to decrypt  communication sniffed by a man in the middle.

There are various ways to do this, like for example compromising the application before it gets even shipped or compromising the victims system and changing the app there or even injecting there into the running process.